# How to print exception stacktrace in Lotus Domino Designer console

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I'd like to look at console output when my agent is run.
Or how to set up file output.

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming you're referring to the java console ? You can display a stack trace or system output by looking under Select File->Tools->Show Java debug console.

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Debugging_Java_agents/index.html) old article is still applicable today for debugging java in Domino.

[This](http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/the-2-headed-beast-debugging-domino-java-agents-with-eclipse) article covers issues with debugging java agents in 8.5, with a bit more [here](http://quickr.pitagora.at/LotusQuickr/thegrumpydeveloper/Main.nsf/h_Index/931DE1694F336E9EC1257690002D3A8D/?OpenDocument) for activating debug for agents